# Unable to fetch the value from array

Tags: php, arrays

This is a array from which i want to extract the values [_answer:protected] and [_correct:protected]

```
Array
(
    [0] => Model_AnswerTypes Object
        (
            [_answer:protected] => True
            [_html:protected] => 
            [_points:protected] => 1
            [_correct:protected] => 1
            [_sortString:protected] => 
            [_sortStringHtml:protected] => 
            [_mapper:protected] => 
        )

    [1] => Model_AnswerTypes Object
        (
            [_answer:protected] => False
            [_html:protected] => 
            [_points:protected] => 1
            [_correct:protected] => 
            [_sortString:protected] => 
            [_sortStringHtml:protected] => 
            [_mapper:protected] => 
        )
)
```

What i am using

```
$key = '_answer:protected';
foreach ($array as $data)
    {
        echo $data[0]->$key;
    }
```

Getting a blank array out of this

Really appreciate any help

Comment: protected is a visibility of that variable.

Comment: Look at my answer to see possible resolutions to the `protected` visibility problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a bit about your model class i think the following may be what you want.

```
foreach ($array as $data)
{
    echo $data->answer; //(assumes Model_AnswerTypes::_get($name) is defined)
}
```

if that doesn't work, try

```
foreach ($array as $data)
{
    echo $data->getAnswer(); // assumes getter/setter pattern
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$key = '_answer:protected';
foreach ($array as $data)
{
    echo $data->$key; // The 0 is not needful because you make a foreach :)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have an array of objects, not straight values.

since the value of the `Model_AnswerTypes` object you want to read is protected, you need to use a method to get it (or the class need to use the __get() magic method).

usual methods are

```
$data->getAnswer();
```

or

```
$data->answer; //if the __get() method is implemented, a more unusual  form would be $data->_answer
```

Comment: this only gives the '_answer' key value how to extract '_correct' key value